# Power Query Mashup Containers at 0% of processor, network, and disk

Tags: excel, powerquery, mashup

I have an excel Power Query report with a surprising bug. *All* of the mashup engine processes have no processor footprint, but exist. The only fix I have right now is to end these processes. The new mashup containers are created and the report continues to load. Why might these dead processes occur? I am not comfortable sharing the code of the problem query here.

Below is the task manager. Per the highlight, those four standing processes are at 0% before I ended them and new instances began.

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: Try enabling Power Query tracing (Data -> Get Data -> Query Options -> Diagnostics -> Enable Tracing) and then inspecting the trace folder. Alternately, take your queries to Power BI and see if the same problems occur there (as PBI is the souped-up version of PQ and has more options for tuning query processing).

Comment: Using PQ in Power BI to inspect the trace, 80% of the time went to. RemoteDocumentEvaluator/Service/OnBeginGetResult ,       
SimpleDocumentEvaluator/GetResult<IPreviewValueSource>,                                                                                     
RemotePreviewValueSource/RunStub,

Comment: Well, that unfortunately tells you nothing, but it was worth a try. I'm afraid that's as far as it goes without an MS dev hooking up a debugger to the thing and seeing what exactly it's waiting on. The other alternative, as I've said, is seeing what happens if PBI runs the same queries; if that does go through, comparing the traces might give some insight. Without the actual query I think this is as far as random people on the Internet can go.

Comment: I ran a version of the query in Power BI and it loads in 5 min, as opposed to the standard 30 in excel even with the dead process deleted in Task Manager. I used Power BI to refactor my query and ran it in Power Query in Excel and got the same result as before. The issue is specific to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You may look at these three articles from Chris Webb's BI Blog:

1. [Monitoring Power Query Memory Usage With Query Diagnostics In Power BI](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/05/21/monitoring-power-query-memory-usage-with-query-diagnostics-in-power-bi/)
2. [Speed Up Power Query In Power BI Desktop By Allocating More Memory To Evaluation Containers](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/06/06/speed-up-power-query-in-power-bi-desktop-by-allocating-more-memory-to-evaluation-containers/)
3. [Speed Up Power Query In Power BI Desktop By Increasing Or Decreasing The Number Of Evaluation Containers](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/06/13/speed-up-power-query-in-power-bi-desktop-by-increasing-or-decreasing-the-number-of-evaluation-containers/)